# How to use inverse distance to a power algorithm in R(not weighted)?

Tags: qgis, r, interpolation

Can some one provide an example R code to replace the GRID (inverse distance to a power) interpolation algorithm in QGIS. I am looking for R code.

Comment: have you read the R Spatial Task View? Or any R documentation? How much R do you know already?

Comment: Hey, I came to R from QGIS as QGIS couldnt handle my large data. Now I am trying to make codes, which avoids QGIS completely.

Comment: How much R have you already learnt? Have you read your spatial data into R? Do we need to start from zero to answer this?

Comment: @Spacedman, I am using R now.  The issues are solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start: (untested)

Supposing you have a spatial points data.frame 'points_spdf' of points with attribute 'z' to be interpolated, and the result grid as 'grd'

```
library(gstat)
pwr = 3.0  # Put you inverse dist power here
interp <- idw(z~1, locations=points_spdf, newdata=grd, idp=pwr)
```

Check help(idw) after you have loaded gstat.

Comment: i believe this is idw, not inverse distance to a power (by gdal)

Comment: R also has a "gdalUtils" package that includes a function `gdal_grid` that implements the additional parameters of Inverse Dist to a Power. I would suggest to the OP to take this question to the r-sig-geo maillist. That's their specialty.